# nginx 403 forbidden error for wordpress main page

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to configure a website with nginx that serves django on main domain and serves wordpress on doamin.com/blog and my django part works completly fine but in wordpress I have the issue that when I'm trying to reach wordpress's main page (domain.com/blog) it gives me a 403 nginx forbidden error. everything else works fine for example I can access wordpress's dashboard and do everything. even when I try going to a url like domain.com/blog/xx it properly shows a (page not found) page in wordpress which is right.
The only problem I have is with domain.com/blog
So because my problem is only with wordpress part I only copied the nginx configuration for it

```
location /blog {
   alias /var/www/example.com;
   try_files $uri $uri/ @blog;

   location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
     include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
location @blog {
  rewrite /blog/(.*)$ /blog/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just removed $uri/ from try_files and everything worked fine